# Upgrade to nopcommerce 3.20 seems to break Plugin Configuration Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

We deployed an e-commerce site based on nopcommerce 3.10 and have developed a couple of plugins for the particular case. Everything was working properly. 
Once version 3.20 was out, we downloaded the full source version, added our plugins and re-compiled the site making any required changes for the plugins as well.

It worked perfectly fine on the development environment (as is usualy the case ) but once we deployed it to the production server there were errors when trying to configure the plugins. Not just ours, almost all plugins.

The error was

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
>
> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request
>   for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Nop.Plugin.Shipping.CSTM.Views.ShippingCSTM.Configure' or its master
>   was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

This was not an issue of the views not being marked as embedded resource, because they were, and worked perfectly with version 3.10.

We even downloaded Visual Studio 2013 and re-compiled the project from a fresh code download while making sure that all the libraries (e.g. Razor, MVC) were in the correct version etc, but we had no luck.

Any ideas on what might the problem? 
The Production server is on a shared hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

We have exactly the same issue as you, just to add information if you deploy debug not release you can't access the admin panel (404 - Page not found).

We where able to build nopCommerce 3.20 from source with VS 2013 and manually copy the content from Presentation\Nop.Web folder to our testing server and it works fine. But the Nop.Web folder contains csproj, cs and other unnecessary files.

(sorry i cannot add a comment because i don't have 50 reputation so i posted an answer)